# What are PDEs of the form $\sum \partial_{tt} w = \sum \partial_{xx}w$ called?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, terminology

Suppose that $w: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a solution to the PDE
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t_i^2} = c^2\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x_i^2}.$$
Is there a name for this PDE? It isn't just the multi-dimensional wave equation as it has an equal number of time and space dimensions.

Furthermore are general solutions to the equation given by $F,G : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ so that $$w(t, x) = F(t -cv) +G(t+cv)$$
Finally what if there are more time dimensions than space dimensions and visa-versa.

Comment: [Ultrahyperbolic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrahyperbolic_equation).

Comment: Thank you for this direction. Might I further ask if my form is a solution?

Comment: Related MSE question [Ultrahyperbolic PDE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14635/ultrahyperbolic-pde)

Comment: I think you mean $F(ct - x) + G(ct + x)$.  Then yes, this is a solution (if $F$ and $G$ are twice differentiable in each variable).  It's not the most general solution though.  For example, $c^2 t_1^2 -  x_2^2$ is a solution not of this form.